# Purpose of include folders in cross compiler

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, sdl-2

I have installed GCC cross compiler for Raspberry Pi to my Ubuntu 20.04 to opt folder. Now When I create new cross compile project I have list of include in my Eclipse project explorer:

```
/opt/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/include
/opt/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include
/opt/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/usr/include
/opt/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.1/usr/include-fixed
```

How Eclipse knows these include folders?

What is purpose of all of these folders? What kind of includes they are defined for?

Suppose I need to use SDL2 library. Where I should place it's header and binary?

Comment: Note: On Unix/BSD and Linux, too, these are "directories" and not the Windows user concept of "folders" which are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this article (which is a little dated) https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/october/article4.php CDT will try to detect built-in compiler symbols and include paths running the compiler with special options and parse the output of this special run. The command will be probably something like: `arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null` supposing the compiler you are using is arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.

All these folders contains include files like stdio.h , stdlib.h ... of libc , libm ... and also some arm specific header files.

If you are not 100% sure, install the cross compiled in a directory all by itself and add the include directory to your eclipse project.